# Behaviour of the marginal in the limit for an infinite sequence of hierarchical priors

Tags: probability, bayesian, prior, hierarchical-bayesian, marginal-distribution

Consider the following model:

$$y \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda_0) \\
\lambda_i | \lambda_{i+1} \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda_i+1) \\
\text{for } i=1,2,\dots,d\\
\lambda_{d+1} = k
$$
With an observed $y=c$.

How does the marginal likelihood given a fixed number $d$ of priors $P_d(y)$ behave as a function of $d$? How about $\lim_{d\to\infty} P_d(y)$

Can a general statement be made for arbitrary distributions?

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bj/1080004760 investigates these sorts of questions

Comment: @Cyan oh wow there's actually a paper on this exact question. I read the abstract, this is definitely going on my steadily growing reading list! Thanks so much for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter of the Exponential distribution is an inverse scale parameter: $X\sim \mathcal E(\lambda)$ can be represented as$$X=\epsilon/\lambda\qquad\epsilon\sim\mathcal E(1)$$Therefore if
$$X \sim \mathcal E(\lambda_0) \\
\lambda_i | \lambda_{i+1} \sim \mathcal E(\lambda_{i+1}) \quad
i=0,1,\dots,d\\
\lambda_{d+1} = 1$$
we can write
\begin{align}X &= \epsilon_0 / \lambda_0 \qquad &\epsilon_0\sim\mathcal E(1)\\
&= \lambda_1 \epsilon_0 / \epsilon_1 \qquad &\epsilon_1\sim\mathcal E(1)\\
&= \epsilon_2 \epsilon_0 / \epsilon_1 \lambda_2 \qquad &\epsilon_2\sim\mathcal E(1)\\
&\quad \vdots\\
&= \frac{\epsilon_{2\lfloor d/2 \rfloor}\cdots \epsilon_0}{\epsilon_{2\lfloor (d-1)/2 \rfloor+1}\cdots \epsilon_1}\qquad &\epsilon_d\sim\mathcal E(1)
\end{align}
and hence
\begin{align*}X&=\frac{\exp\left\{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor}\log\epsilon_{2i}\right\}}{\exp\left\{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor (d-1)/2 \rfloor}\log\epsilon_{2i+1}\right\}}\qquad \epsilon_i\sim\mathcal E(1)\\
&=\frac{\exp\left\{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor}\log\{-\log\upsilon_{2i}\}\right\}}{\exp\left\{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor (d-1)/2 \rfloor}\log\{-\log\upsilon_{2i+1}\}\right\}}
\qquad \upsilon_i\sim\mathcal U(0,1)\end{align*}
appears as the ratio of two independent random variables both [converging a.s. to zero with $d$,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2028514/14893) hence having no limiting distribution. (This property generalises to other scale distributions, obviously, provided $\mathbb E[\sqrt{\epsilon_i}]<1$.)

Considering the general case $\lambda_d\sim\mathcal E(k)$ simply means alternatively multiplying and dividing by $k$ the above, hence preventing any form of convergence.

**Note [update]:** [Corey Yanovski](http://itschancy.wordpress.com/) pointed out to me that this problem is investigated in [“Infinite hierarchies and prior distributions”](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bj/1080004760) by Gareth O. Roberts and Jeffrey S. Rosenthal ([Bernoulli](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bj/1080004760), 2001). The introduction reads as follows:

> Suppose   that   we   had   independent   data   from   an $Exp(\theta_0)$   distribution.   In   a   Bayesian framework,   we  suppose  that   a  priori $\theta_0\sim Exp(\theta_1)$,  and  that  with  uncertainty  on  the hyperparameter $\theta_1$,  we  might  also  give  it  a  prior, $\theta_1\sim Exp(\theta_2)$  say.  In  fact  at  each  level  of  the hierarchy we can hedge our bets by imposing a further level of prior uncertainty. Suppose we impose $N$ levels  of  the  hierarchy  by  fixing  the  hyperparameter $\theta_N$ and  sequentially  setting
> $$\theta_i\sim Exp(\theta_{i+1})\qquad i=N-1,N-2,..., 1, 0$$ In terms of the data, the only thing that matters is the marginal prior of $\theta_0$,  obtained  (if  it  were  possible)  by  integrating  out  the  hierarchical  parameters.In  such  a  situation,  it  is  natural  to  consider  the  prior  distribution  of $\theta$ as $N\uparrow\infty$. In this  case  and  many others,  no  proper  distributional  limit  exists,  but  the  limit  can  sometimes still  be  described  in  terms  of  an  improper  prior  distribution.

Comment: are there any general statements or results relating to larger and larger hierarchical models?
thanks for the answer, that was a clever way to go about it...